# gdb can not find source files compiled by cc

Tags: debugging, gdb, cc

I have a source file testcc.c which just print a "Hello, World", I compile it with cc as below

```
cc -g -o testcc testcc.c
```

it works fine when I run it.
now I want to debug it with gdb with the following command.

```
gdb testcc
```

I can see the output from gdb.

> GDB is free software and you are welcome to distribute copies of it 
>   under certain conditions; type "show copying" to see the conditions.
>   There is absolutely no warranty for GDB; type "show warranty" for
>   details. GDB 4.16 (sparc-sun-solaris2.6), Copyright 1996 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc...

But, When I try to set a breakpoint at line 5, I got the following message

```
(gdb) break 5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10814: file /home/users/xxx/C, line 5.
(gdb)
```

The problem is /home/users/xxx/C is my current working directory, not the source file!

Then, I try to use the file:line-number options

```
(gdb) break testcc.c:5
No source file named testcc.c.
```

So, I include the full path for the file name as below

```
(gdb) break /home/users/xxx/testcc.c:5
No source file named /home/users/xxx/testcc.c.
```

I am confused, the file is there, why gdb can not find it?
I also try to specify the directory to search for source files when starting gdb

```
gdb -d /home/users/xxx/C testcc
```

it still not work, what's the problem?

Comment: Is `/home/users/xxx/C` a real directory or have you mounted a Windows file system on your Solaris system ?

Comment: Do you see the message "Reading symbols from /path/to/your/cc/file...done." on startup? Also, GDB seems to be at version 7.4.1 on my Linux box, so 4.16 looks reeeaaally old to me... Finally, just to be sure, try gdb ./testcc (there might be another testcc in the path)

Comment: Try grabbing a more recent version of GDB from http://www.sunfreeware.com/. I suspect your `gdb`, version 4.16 (sparc-sun-solaris2.6), is having trouble with the debugging information generated by your copy of `gcc`.

Comment: @Paul R, that's a real directory.

Comment: @Sjlver, I didn't see that message, I have tried gdb ./testcc, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @scott, I am not using gcc, I use cc, will try new version of gdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggle for a whole day, I finally find that we should use dbx to debug program compiled by Sun cc compiler. here is the link said this.

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/